# String, word to word translation

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary, translation

I have a class as

```
class dictonary
{
  public string English{get;set;}
  public string Hindi{get;set;}
}
```

Here i have a list of class dictionary as `List<dictionary>` having meaning in English and Hindi.
I want function as

```
public string EngToHindi(string English)
{
   private string hindi="";
   //nepali = english =>Logic goes here
   return hindi;
}
```

If I pass string like `"My Name Is Manoj."`
then it must return `"Mera Naam hai Manoj"`

`List<dictionary>` I have data data as

```
   English   Hindi
---------------------
    my        mera
    is        hai
    Name     naam
```

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you want to leverage the _actual_ [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class so you can create a lookup table. EDIT: Then you'd have something like `Dictionary<string, string> EnglishToHindi = ...; string hindiWord = EnglishToHindi["my"];`

Comment: I don't see this working for more complex sentences.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair i think that is good but i have no much knowledge about Dictionary so i am using list.

Comment: Have you considered using translation apis such as Google Translate? (would require a web connection I think)

Comment: @Sayse acctualyy this is only situation for my problem so i need to use create my own api.

Comment: @manoj: no time like the present to learn! `Dictionary` usage in C# is common place and an often-used tool in many typical C# applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Dictionary class. it works perfect. this is the complete program you can use. it's easy and it will define the whole line!! happy coding! ;)

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // initialize your dictionary
        myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

        // fill the dictionary
        // you should fill if from file or database or something!
        myDictionary.Add("my", "mera");
        myDictionary.Add("is", "hai");
        myDictionary.Add("name", "naam");

        // the line you want to define in english:
        string line = "my name is Shamim";

        // output defined line in hindi:
        string output = EngLineToHindi(line);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static string EngLineToHindi(string line)
    {
        // array of words:
        string[] words = line.Split(' ');
        string ToReturn = "";
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            string temp = EngToHindi(word) + " ";
            ToReturn += temp;
        }
        return ToReturn;
    }
    static string EngToHindi(string EngWord)
    {
        string key1 = EngWord;
        // if not has the meaning return the same word!
        if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(key1)) return EngWord;
        else return myDictionary[key1];
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, you should test this in a "Console Application" though!

Answer (score -1):

Here is something that might work...

```
Dictionary<string, string> EnglishHindiTranslations = null;

public void Populate()
{
    EnglishHindiTranslations = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    EnglishHindiTranslations.Add("my","mera");
    EnglishHindiTranslations.Add("is","hai");
    EnglishHindiTranslations.Add("Name","naam");
}

public string TranslateHindiToEnglish(string hindiWord)
{
    string value = EnglishHindiTranslations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == hindiWord).Key;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
         return hindiWord;
    }

    return value;
 }

public string TranslateEnglishToHindi(string englishWord)
{
    string value = EnglishHindiTranslations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == englishWord).Value;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
         return englishWord;
    }

    return value;
}
```